# I Have got this error when i run flutter app on windows

Tags: flutter

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
Generator

```
Visual Studio 16 2019
```

could not find any instance of Visual Studio.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then update your question to provide more details about your issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just install visual studio 16 community from
[here](https://www.techspot.com/downloads/7241-visual-studio-2019.html)